# Angular 14: Dynamic SVG Component renders elements but isn't visible on screen

Tags: angular, svg

I'm working on an app that parses SVG and saves it as a JSON object which can be dynamically rendered with a custom component I created.  Even though everything works and I can see all the elements in the inspector, nothing shows up on the screen for some reason.  I originally created this back in angular 9 and it worked back then however as I'm recreating it in Angular 14 things aren't working like they did.

Back when I created it we had to add `svg:` to the beginning of our elements and my custom component had to be `<svg:g my-component>` in order to work.  I remember there was an update that eliminated the need for the `svg:` part but now I'm wondering if there's some new trick we need to do now with the latest version of Angular.

As of right now the way I have my svg templates set up looks like this.

**svg-builder template**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<style type="text/css" *ngIf="GlobalStyling !== ''" [innerHtml]="insertStyles()"></style>

  <defs>
      <symbol #symbolShell [attr.id]="SvgData.graphicId" [attr.viewBox]="GraphicViewBox">

          <svg-component *ngFor="let item of SvgData.elements" [ElementData]="item"></svg-component>

      </symbol>
  </defs>
  

  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <use [attr.xlink:href]="SymbolLink" />
  </svg>

</svg>
```

**svg-component template**

```
<svg>

  <g *ngIf="TemplateType === 'single element'" [innerHtml]="insertElement()"></g>

  <g #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType == 'group element'">

      <svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg-component>

  </g>

  <linearGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

      <svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg-component>

  </linearGradient>

  <radialGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'radial gradient'">

      <svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg-component>

  </radialGradient>

  <symbol #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

      <svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg-component>

  </symbol>

</svg>
```

In order to experiment with it for yourself you can [go here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g9pacu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Finterfaces.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-selector-input%2Fmedia-selector-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-expression-input%2Fmedia-expression-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-selector-input%2Fmedia-selector-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fviewbox-input%2Fviewbox-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-expression-input%2Fmedia-expression-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-input-component%2Ftext-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.svg,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-component%2Fsvg.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.svg,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fsvg-builder.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Ffunctions%2Fshape-graphic-data.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Ffunctions%2Fsplit-svg-to-elements.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fviewbox-input%2Fviewbox-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fcode-input-component%2Fcode-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fstyling-input.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-query-input.component.html,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-selector-input%2Fmedia-selector-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-type-input%2Fmedia-type-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-expression-input%2Fmedia-expression-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fcomponents%2Fstyling-input%2Fmedia-query-input%2Fmedia-expression-input%2Fmedia-expression-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-parser%2Fsvg-parser.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finterfaces.ts) and fill out the form with the following content.

**1. Go to the `demo.svg` file located in the `svg-builder` folder and paste the code into the `svg input`.** *(I originally pasted the code here but it exceeded the 30k character limit)*

**2. Add anything you want to the `title` and `graphic id` inputs.**

**3. For the `viewbox` settings enter `x=0 y=0 width=144 height=144`**

**4.  In the `Global Styling` input paste this code**

```
.st0{fill:#0038A8;}
.st1{fill:#141414;}
```

**5. Scroll down and click the `submit` button**

**6. Scroll beneath the JSON that pops up and click the `Build SVG` button**

Once you do this and look in the `elements` tab of the inspector you'll see that everything renders in the browser, it just doesn't show up on the screen.  I've tried tinkering with some of the older ways we had to use to get it to render that I mentioned above and nothing seems to work.  Does anybody know why this is happening and what we need to do?

Comment: Wrong namespace I imagine.

Comment: Angular doesn't replace the selector's, so HTML would be `<symbol><svg-component><svg><g>...</g></svg><svg-component><symbol>`, do you think this can cause SVG issue? the unrecognisable SVG selector(`svg-component`) introduced inside `SVG` element

Comment: It worked a few versions back, which is why we had to use `<svg:g my-component>...</svg:g>` but now when I try that I get an error from trying to bind data to the `@Input()` telling me that attribute doesn't exist on the `<g>` element. if I try adding `attr.` to the binding it just has a value of `[object, object]` and doesn't render any internal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after some digging around I found a solution that works.  In the `svg-component` I need to define the selector like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'svg:g[svg-component]',
  ...
})
```

When I use the component in my template I have to do `<svg:g svg-component>...</svg:g>` and everything works as expected.